# Is it possible to create a DEFAULT clause with an incrementing identifier?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know whether it is possible to achieve something like the following in PostgreSQL:

I have a table named `Dossier` (means "folder" in English), with the the following table structure: `name, taille`,...

Now, what I'd like to have on my table is a condition such that each time a new instance of `Dossier` is created, the value in the `name` column is automatically supplemented with a self-incrementing identifier like so: `ref00001`, `ref00002` etc. (To clarify, after the second insertion, the value for the `name` column should be `ref00002` automatically...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_ref;

CREATE TABLE dossier
        (
        ref TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'ref' || NEXTVAL('seq_ref'),
        value TEXT
        );
```

If you want zero-padded numbers, use this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_ref;

CREATE TABLE dossier
        (
        ref TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'ref' || LPAD(NEXTVAL('seq_ref')::TEXT, 10, '0'),
        value TEXT
        );
```

Comment: While this is possible, it's also usually a really bad idea in data model terms. Where possible store the folder number separately and format it for output, like `SELECT ref||to_char(folderno,'00000') FROM dossier`. Be aware that if you use a `SEQUENCE` then it can have holes (gaps), so you might get `ref00001`, `ref00002`, `ref00004`, etc.

Comment: this is true as you said .. in some cases there will be no respect for the incrimentation .. why some time after  ref00001 going to ref00008 !!!!